# Has Gomez' goatee something to do with Walter in season 4?

Tags: character, breaking-bad

In season 4 of *Breaking Bad* Gomez has grown a goatee. Is there some sort of link to Walter or something? It is after all his "trademark". So I thought they wouldn't just give anybody one, or am I just looking for  something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to Steven Michael Quezada](http://www.rollingstone.com/tv/news/breaking-bad-q-a-partner-up-with-steven-michael-quezadas-gomez-20130906):

> To me, for a cop, Gomez is sort of a goofy, not-very-confident kind of
>   guy. That was cool with me – that was the character, that's who he
>   was. He grew, though. All that's happened since he separated from
>   Hank, when they sent him to El Paso and **he came back with a beard
>   [laughs] – like a growing-up, becoming-a-man kind of thing, you know?
>   He's a little tougher, a little more confident.**